# Concatenar numeros en excel para crear una fecha

Tags: excel, vba

estoy trabajando en excel tratanto de concatenar 3 celdas para obtener una fecha, usando la funcion "=FECHA(C61,D61,E61)" esas son mis celdas pero en la celda obtengo una fecha mas antigua y no se de donde sale esa fecha que no son para nada los valores de las celdas.

Tambien encontre otras maneras de concatenar pero solo esta es la que necesito por que despues de concatenar debo hacer una comparacion con otra fecha para saber si son iguales, menudo problema.
Si a alguien se le presento algun problema similar una ayuda me vendria bien gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué valores introduces, y qué fecha obtienes?

Comment: No será que estas tratando de pasar a fecha una celda con un valor no esperado, como por ejemplo un 31 de Noviembre?.

Comment: Debe ser eso, al menos en español el Formato es Fecha(año, mes , dia) , si pones valores que no corresponden te muestra una fecha antigua.

Comment: Asegurate también que tienes la celda en formato General/Standard, por si acaso, para ver que te devuelve una fecha por defecto. Teniendo en cuenta que estás separando los argumentos por comas, tiene la pinta de que tu Excel tiene una configuración regional distinta a Español España, y podría ser que la estructura de tu fórmula FECHA sea diferente.